# Mapsforge Austria map error

Tags: openstreetmap, mapsforge

I have tried download Austria map from http://download.mapsforge.org/ and generate Austria map file by myself (osmosis-0.43.1, mapsforge-map-writer-0.4.0) too. But they give same issue.
Some data map near Perchtoldsdorf are missing at zoom level>=12.

The error message:

> 09-05 10:52:30.745: E/MapsforgeTileProvider(4279):
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid latitude:
>   -90.14254932030728 09-05 10:52:30.745: E/MapsforgeTileProvider(4279):     at
>   org.mapsforge.core.util.LatLongUtils.validateLatitude(LatLongUtils.java:172)
>   09-05 10:52:30.745: E/MapsforgeTileProvider(4279):    at
>   org.mapsforge.core.model.LatLong.(LatLong.java:46) 09-05
>   10:52:30.745: E/MapsforgeTileProvider(4279):  at
>   org.mapsforge.map.reader.MapDatabase.decodeWayNodesDoubleDelta(MapDatabase.java:356)
>   09-05 10:52:30.745: E/MapsforgeTileProvider(4279):    at
>   org.mapsforge.map.reader.MapDatabase.processWayDataBlock(MapDatabase.java:674)
>   09-05 10:52:30.745: E/MapsforgeTileProvider(4279):    at
>   org.mapsforge.map.reader.MapDatabase.processWays(MapDatabase.java:780)
>   09-05 10:52:30.745: E/MapsforgeTileProvider(4279):    at
>   org.mapsforge.map.reader.MapDatabase.processBlock(MapDatabase.java:449)
>   09-05 10:52:30.745: E/MapsforgeTileProvider(4279):    at
>   org.mapsforge.map.reader.MapDatabase.processBlocks(MapDatabase.java:538)
>   09-05 10:52:30.745: E/MapsforgeTileProvider(4279):    at
>   org.mapsforge.map.reader.MapDatabase.readMapData(MapDatabase.java:321)
>   09-05 10:52:30.745: E/MapsforgeTileProvider(4279):    at
>   org.mapsforge.map.layer.renderer.DatabaseRenderer.executeJob(DatabaseRenderer.java:169)
>   09-05 10:52:30.745: E/MapsforgeTileProvider(4279):    at
>   at.xylem.mapin.mapext.MapsforgeTileProvider.readTileImage(MapsforgeTileProvider.java:75)
>   09-05 10:52:30.745: E/MapsforgeTileProvider(4279):    at
>   at.xylem.mapin.mapext.MapsforgeTileProvider.getTile(MapsforgeTileProvider.java:67)
>   09-05 10:52:30.745: E/MapsforgeTileProvider(4279):    at
>   com.google.android.gms.maps.model.TileOverlayOptions$2.getTile(Unknown
>   Source) 09-05 10:52:30.745: E/MapsforgeTileProvider(4279):    at
>   com.google.android.gms.maps.model.internal.g$a.onTransact(Unknown
>   Source) 09-05 10:52:30.745: E/MapsforgeTileProvider(4279):    at
>   android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:361) 09-05 10:52:30.745:
>   E/MapsforgeTileProvider(4279):    at gwl.a(SourceFile:96) 09-05
>   10:52:30.745: E/MapsforgeTileProvider(4279):  at gve.a(SourceFile:73)
>   09-05 10:52:30.745: E/MapsforgeTileProvider(4279):    at owd.run(Unknown
>   Source) 09-05 10:52:30.745: E/MapsforgeTileProvider(4279):    at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
>   09-05 10:52:30.745: E/MapsforgeTileProvider(4279):    at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 09-05
>   10:52:30.745: E/MapsforgeTileProvider(4279):  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:152)
>   09-05 10:52:30.745: E/MapsforgeTileProvider(4279):    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:265)
>   09-05 10:52:30.745: E/MapsforgeTileProvider(4279):    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>   09-05 10:52:30.745: E/MapsforgeTileProvider(4279):    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>   09-05 10:52:30.745: E/MapsforgeTileProvider(4279):    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

I also try Austria map at http://www.openandromaps.org/ and it's OK but the map file size quite big (~400Mb). (The Austria map file from download.mapsforge.org or created my me ~ 210Mb).

Anyone have any solutions to fix this?
(I have posted at https://code.google.com/p/mapsforge/issues/detail?id=519&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Owner%20Summary%20Modified but no feedback)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid latitude: -90.14254932030728
```

I'd be looking very closely into that, latitude is supposed to be a value between -90 and 90.

Since Austria is around the 40-50N mark, I'd say that was a data error in the files you've downloaded, or an error in the code that handles zooming.

Given the known issues on the MapsForge site are:

- It is known that these maps have problems displaying some water areas correctly.
- The build for some of the maps has failed. We are trying to bring these maps to you shortly.

I'm not sure how much faith I'd put in them.

Comment: I know the invalid value come from a calculate function and I sure that this error made by some changed in the new version of Map Writer lib, Because IT WORK AS WELL with map download from openandromaps.org.
2. Which offline map can use instead Mapsforge? Can you suggest me one?
I have tried OSMAnd but It can't integrate into my app because it's completed App source code, it's not a library. I also try some libraries which using image tiles or MBtile but the map size too large (e.x Vienna map, zoom 7-18 = 163Mb) so It's not useful.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem via use the old mapsforge writer version (0.3.0)

I guess the checking valid data function was removed in the new version.

I saw some warning message about invalid data during generate the map file with map writer version 0.3.0